# Не получается достать значение с формы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, позиционирование

Всем привет. Есть магазин и секция с двумя товарами: один статический, второй вариативный. Цену на товары абсолютно позиционирую внутри контейнера  в зависимости от содержимого. Содержимое кода товаров во многом совпадают, но для статического товара высоту скрипт переопределяет все верно, а для динамического переопределения не происходит. наглядно это можно видеть: [здесь в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddupm8d8/1/)

Я понял в чем дело - в динамическом товаре цена формируется в атрибуте формы `data-product_variations`, а не в теге с классом `.price`. Вопрос как достать ценник остается открытым

```
<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product_id="3348" data-product_variations="[{&quot;variation_id&quot;:3361,&quot;variation_is_visible&quot;:true,&quot;variation_is_active&quot;:true,&quot;is_purchasable&quot;:true,&quot;display_price&quot;:260000,&quot;display_regular_price&quot;:260000,&quot;attributes&quot;:{&quot;attribute_pa_size&quot;:&quot;medium&quot;},&quot;image_src&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_link&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_alt&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;price_html&quot;:&quot;<span class=\&quot;price\&quot;><span class=\&quot;amount\&quot;>260.000&nbsp;руб.<\/span><\/span>&quot;,&quot;availability_html&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;sku&quot;:&quot;PS104-1&quot;,&quot;weight&quot;:&quot; kg&quot;,&quot;dimensions&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;min_qty&quot;:1,&quot;max_qty&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;backorders_allowed&quot;:false,&quot;is_in_stock&quot;:true,&quot;is_downloadable&quot;:false,&quot;is_virtual&quot;:false,&quot;is_sold_individually&quot;:&quot;no&quot;},{&quot;variation_id&quot;:3362,&quot;variation_is_visible&quot;:true,&quot;variation_is_active&quot;:true,&quot;is_purchasable&quot;:true,&quot;display_price&quot;:130000,&quot;display_regular_price&quot;:130000,&quot;attributes&quot;:{&quot;attribute_pa_size&quot;:&quot;small&quot;},&quot;image_src&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_link&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_alt&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;price_html&quot;:&quot;<span class=\&quot;price\&quot;><span class=\&quot;amount\&quot;>130.000&nbsp;руб.<\/span><\/span>&quot;,&quot;availability_html&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;sku&quot;:&quot;PS104-2&quot;,&quot;weight&quot;:&quot; kg&quot;,&quot;dimensions&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;min_qty&quot;:1,&quot;max_qty&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;backorders_allowed&quot;:false,&quot;is_in_stock&quot;:true,&quot;is_downloadable&quot;:false,&quot;is_virtual&quot;:false,&quot;is_sold_individually&quot;:&quot;no&quot;}]">
```

Comment: неужели ни у кого не возникло умной мысли? ведь проблема же воспроизводима!

Comment: Если честно, то в наглядном примере вообще ни чего не понятно. Наглядности нет ;) из-за этого и мыслей умных тоже нет.

Comment: @Visman ну смотрите, проблема же воспроизводится: если пройти по ссылке выше и открыть редактор, то четко видно, что в простом товаре `top` с помощью скрипта переопределился относительно изначального, а в вариативном нет

Comment: http://jpegshare.net/images/d1/e7/d1e7711800ec3ba43dde121e79152004.png Вот как у меня в двух браузерах пример отображается :(

Comment: @Visman странно.. ну тогда давай на 2ой ориентироваться
вот, что у меня показывает:
http://s017.radikal.ru/i404/1507/cf/ee912b962c53.png
http://s017.radikal.ru/i402/1507/cb/4d722914a495.png

Comment: @Visman вообщем, я понял, что цена формируется в атрибуте `data-product_variations`, а не блоке с классом `.price` - добавил в описание. осталось только ее оттуда как-то выцепить..